# data.stackexchange getting response not as Text or HTML but like from API

Tags: support

Not sure if this is the right place to ask

Is there a way to 'query' data.stackexchange.com on a premade custom query in such a way that I would get a response not as text or html table, but just raw data (JSON) like you would get from API..

Basically I have created this static jsfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/ztqfmvff/ and ATM it is using static data that I have transformed manually...

I now want to make automatic feed from this query https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/585579

Chances are someone before me needed to run and extract something more complicated then basic select by id... If there is a way it would be much more convenient to get this data as JSON instead of having to hack-extract it from page....

Is there a way to query a custom query data.stackexchange as API?